# Custom ScrollView with identical inertia and drag gesture effects as native SwiftUI ScrollView

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui, scrollview, draggesture

I want to implement scrollview with snap effect + looped content and native SwiftUI ScrollView don't provide such wide customization (may be somebody will correct me), so I decided to implement my own. I'm managed to make initial drag gesture (but it breaks logic with predictedEndLocation if user drag in the middle of animation) and scrolling to predictedEndLocation. But what I don't understand is how to gradually decrease speed of animation as xoffset get closer to predictedEndLocation.x, so it looks like inertia effect in SwiftUI native ScrolView. So, to sum up I need help to implement inertia effect same as in ScrollView and fix problem with "TapGesture" between animation of inertia.

Code:

```
struct InfiniteSnapCarousel<T:Equatable, Content: View>: View where T: Identifiable {
    @State private var items: [T]
    @State private var xOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGFloat = .zero
    @ViewBuilder private var content: (T) -> Content
    private let spacing: CGFloat
    private let itemWidth: CGFloat
    private let itemHeight: CGFloat
    
    init(
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            LazyHStack(spacing: spacing){
                ForEach(items){ item in
                    content(item)
                        .frame(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
                        .offset(x: xOffset)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged({ value in
                                    loopCarousel(after: item)
                                    withAnimation(.linear) {
                                        self.onDragChanged(value)
                                    }
                                })
                                .onEnded({ value in
                                    
                                    withAnimation(.linear) {
                                        self.onDragEnded(value, geo: geo)
                                    }
                                }))
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                xOffset = geo.size.width / 2 - itemWidth / 2
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func onDragChanged(_ value: DragGesture.Value) {
        self.xOffset = lastOffset + value.translation.width
    }
    
    private func onDragEnded(_ value: DragGesture.Value, geo: GeometryProxy) {
        lastOffset = xOffset

        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                    let contentCenterX = value.predictedEndLocation.x + geo.size.width / 2
                    let imaginaryItemWidth = itemWidth + spacing
                    let index = Int(contentCenterX / imaginaryItemWidth)
                    xOffset = CGFloat(index) * imaginaryItemWidth + itemWidth / 2 + spacing
                    lastOffset = xOffset
                }
    }
```